# Optaplanner 6.1.0 cr1

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to implement a Value Range for an entities planning variable. The variable is defined as

```
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"xPosRange"})
public BigDecimal getXCenter()
{
    return xCenter;
}
```

The ValueRangeProvider is specified as

```
@ValueRangeProvider(id = "xPosRange")
public CountableValueRange<BigDecimal> getXPositions()
{
    return ValueRangeFactory.createBigDecimalValueRange(new BigDecimal(0.0,
            MathContext.DECIMAL64), new BigDecimal(maxLength, MathContext.DECIMAL64));
}
```

Ideally I would like to have this within the Planning Entity. However, the values are never changed when the solution is being solved. The same is true when the "ValueRangeProvider" is added to the solution.

Do the "CountableValueRange" collections need to be added to the problem facts?
If so how, adding

```
facts.addAll(getXPositions());
```

raises an argument mismatch error.

I have tried to add the following to the xml config file

```
<changeMoveSelector>
    <valueSelector>
      <variableName>xCenter</variableName>
    </valueSelector>
</changeMoveSelector>
```

However, this raises a runtime error stating the xCenter has no "getter" within the entity.

```
The selectorConfig (ValueSelectorConfig(xCenter)) has a variableName (xCenter) for
entityClass (packetName.Part) that does not have that as a getter.
Check the spelling of the variableName (xCenter)
```

Please can anyone point me in the correct direction. Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind changing the title to something more question specific?

Answer (score 1):

"Do the CountableValueRange collections need to be added to the problem facts?" No. That would require enumerating them, which is unrealistic for large value ranges (all possible longs for example).

"However, this raises a runtime error stating the xCenter has no getter within the entity." I suspect that your issue has nothing to do with the use of the `CountableValueRange<BigDecimal>`, but has everything to do with the variable property name `xCenter`. Motivation for this theory:

1. The error message speaks about not finding the planning variable (= step 2), not about not finding the value range (= step 3). It did find the planning entity successfully (= step 1).
2. The JavaBeans specification related to the getters of `getXCenter()` and `getAFoo()` and `getHTTPSomething()` are strange/illogical, if I recall correctly. I suspect `getXCenter()` leads to a property name of **`XCenter` instead of `xCenter`** (and yes, the JavaBeans spec suck in that regard, but OptaPlanner has to adhere to the JavaBeans spec).

Answer (score 1):

I've improved the error message for 6.1.0.CR2, so you 'd get something like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The selectorConfig (ValueSelectorConfig(pEriod)) has a variableName (pEriod) which is not a valid planning variable on entityClass (class org.optaplanner.examples.curriculumcourse.domain.Lecture).
The variableName (pEriod) for entityClass (class org.optaplanner.examples.curriculumcourse.domain.Lecture) does not exists as a property (getter/setter) on that class.
Check the spelling of the variableName (pEriod). It probably needs to be correctedVariableName (PEriod) instead because the JavaBeans spec states the first letter should be a upper case if the second is upper case.
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.SelectorConfig.deduceVariableDescriptor(SelectorConfig.java:100)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.value.ValueSelectorConfig.buildValueSelector(ValueSelectorConfig.java:198)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMoveSelectorConfig.buildBaseMoveSelector(ChangeMoveSelectorConfig.java:68)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.MoveSelectorConfig.buildMoveSelector(MoveSelectorConfig.java:187)
```